# My php isn't making to proper connection to my database using WAMP.

Tags: php, html, mysql

This project involves connecting to a database using phpMyAdmin. I have a file named index.php which presents the user with a simple form that connects to a file for processing called functions.php. I'm using WAMP to connect everything but when I try running everything the form and submit work but after the form is submitted the next page displays nothing when it should be displaying some information even if its an error message. I really can't figure out what's wrong. I've already created the database on phpMyAdmin by importing a file containing sql code to create all my tables for a relational database. Here is the code, any help is appreciated.

index.php

```
  <form action="functions.php" method="post">
    First Name: <input type = "text" name = "Fname"><br>
    <!-- Last Name: <input type = "text" name = "Lname"><br>
    Commision: <input type = "text" name = "commision"><br>
    Phone Number: <input type = "text" name = "phone"><br>
    Job Title: <input type = "text" name = "job"><br> -->
    <input type="submit">
  </form>

</body>
```

functions.php

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$username = 'kempenaar';
$password = 'Jayson38!';
$db_name = '3660Project';
//$Fname = $_POST["Fname"];

echo "in the script";

 $conn = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password,$db_name)

 if(!$conn)
 {
   die ('Error connecting to MySQL server.' . mysql_error());
 }

 $db_select = mysql_select_db($db_name);

 if(!$db_select)
 {
     die('Can\'t use ' . $db_name . ': ' . mysql_error());
 }

$sql = "INSERT INTO Employee (First_Name, Last_Name, Commision, Phone_number, Job)
VALUES ($_POST["Fname"], $_POST["Lname"], $_POST["commision"], $_POST["phone"], $_POST["job"])";

if(mysql_query($sql)){
    echo "Records inserted successfully.";
    header('Location: http://localhost:8888/3660Project/');

} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysql_error($conn);
}

echo "made it here";
?>
```

Comment: view source on next page, is it blank or showing php? at the top of your php page add: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ini_set('html_errors', 0); error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: its showing http://localhost:8888/3660Project/functions.php